# Regular expression to Replace special characters from node property in neo4j

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I have a property whose value may contain following characters: `~!@#$%^&*()` and the space character.

I want to replace all of them with an empty string.

Please suggest a suitable regular expression to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the regular expression, it's the class of all the characters you listed:

```
[~!@#$%^&*() ]
```

You just have to replace all occurrences by an empty string, using the regex/string API of your language.

For example, in Java:

```java
// The pattern can be declared as a constant, computed only once.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[~!@#$%^&*() ]");

String newPropName = p.matcher(propName).replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a thus-far undocumented [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) function, `apoc.text.replace`, that you can use from your Cypher code. It accepts a regular expression as its second parameter. *(Since it is a function, it is not invoked in a `CALL` clause.)*

For example:

```
RETURN apoc.text.replace('~!@1~!@', '[~!@#$%^&*() ]', '') AS res;
```

returns:

```
╒═══╕
│res│
╞═══╡
│1  │
└───┘
```